# Borders around UIButton on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm working on a project where I want the `UIButton` to span across the width of the screen.

I've configured the constraints like this:

[image]

This works perfectly on all iOS devices except the iPhone 6 Plus. As seen on the image below the iPhone 6 Plus is the only device where it doesn't start from the edges of the screen.

[image]

How can I have the `UIButton` go from edge to edge on the iPhone 6 Plus too?

Comment: Uncheck constraint to margins and set left right to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the Option **Constrain to margins**

Set left and right margin to 0.

Do as following screenshot.

[image]